# Adding methods with template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a hash table container called Map with the following method:

```
Value Map<Key, Value>::valueFor(const Key& key);
```

Unfortunately, the most used case is for `Key = std::string` where we usually call the method with string literals such as:

```
const Value v = map.valueFor("my_key");
```

We loose a few cycles creating the `std::string`. Therefore, I would like to add an overload

```
Value Map<std::string, Value>::valueFor(const char* key);
```

when `Key = std::string`. I am sure that the compiler can even compute the hash at compile time with such a signature which would also help to speedup things.

Is there a way to do that in `C++11` without template specializing the whole Map class and rewrite all the methods?

Comment: This smells of premature optimization. Have you actually *measured* that this is a bottleneck?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you implement your own hashed type, instead of using [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) (which happens to be a hashed map data type)?

Comment: @Some programmer dude : Yes, it can slow down things a bit. For `std::unordered_map`, it is far from optimal. The standard prevents using an open addressing hash table which is faster than any standard library implementation of `std::unordered_map`. Have a look at Google dense hash map if you are interested.
Besides, I work on software optimization and I really care about speed.

Comment: My general advice is that "speed" isn't everything. Correctness and maintainability is often *much* more important. "Good enough" usually *is* good enough. Using your own data structures also means you have to reimplement all code around them as well, meaning you have more code-bloat and much larger chances of bugs. Also, optimizations tend to make code unreadable and unmaintainable even with documentation and comments. First make sure your programs works, then *measure* and *profile* to find the worst bottlenecks, and optimize only those (***iff*** not "good enough").

Comment: @some programmer dude : Program optimization is my job, so this is what pays the bill. As a consequence, it is both important for me and my clients. And many optimizations can be done with clean code, wether you like it or not. Some of them make it the code harder to maintain, but in that case decide the tradeoff between speed and ease of maintenance. I have managed to get both x100 speedup and better maintainability with some codes.
Concerning this optimization, I'll know if it is worth it when it is implemented and I have some benchmark with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add another overload `valueFor(char const * key)`.  Probably you then also want to disable this overload with SFINAE if the `Key` is not `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template < typename Key, typename Value >
struct Map
{
    Value valueFor(Key const& key)
    {
        std::cout << "valueFor(const Key& key)\n";
        return Value{};
    }

    template < typename _Key = Key,
               typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_same < _Key, std::string >::value >::type >
    Value valueFor(char const * key)
    {
        std::cout << "valueFor(char const * key)\n";
        return Value{};
    }
};

int main()
{
    Map<std::string, int> map;
    int v = map.valueFor("my_key");

    Map<int, int> other_map;
  //int v = other_map.valueFor("my_key"); // BOOM!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just weaken your type requirements. Your `valueFor` doesn't (need to) care what type the argument is, so long as the expression `hash<Key>(arg)` is valid.

So, you can template `valueFor` on its argument type, and just specialise your hash function and if necessary your key comparator.

eg. (untested, and using C++17 `string_view` for brevity)

```
template <typename K>
struct Hasher
{
  static size_t hash(K const &k) { return std::hash<K>()(k); }
};
template <>
struct Hasher<std::string>
{
  static size_t hash(std::string const &s) {
    return std::hash<std::string>()(s);
  }
  static size_t hash(std::string_view const &sv) {
    return std::hash<std::string_view>()(sv);
  }
  static size_t hash(const char *cstr) {
    return std::hash<std::string_view>()({cstr});
  }
};

template <typename Key, typename Value>
template <typename KeyArg>
Value Map<Key,Value>::valueFor(KeyArg&& arg)
{
    auto hash = Hasher<Key>::hash(std::forward<KeyArg>(arg));
    // ...
}
```